# White page when trying to render content

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I'm attempting to render a template with dynamic content using this code:

```
function render($content, $template = 'main') {
    $base = Base::instance();
    $base->set('content', "ex1/views/$content.htm");
    return \Template::instance()->render("../templates/$template.htm");
}
```

**Route**:

```
/ = thisfolder\ex1\controllers\Controller
```

**Controller**:

```
<?php
namespace thisfolder\ex1\controllers;
class Controller extends \Controller {
    function get() {
        render('index');
    }
}
```

In my config, I have UI set to `UI=app/thisfolder/`.
**Stucture**:

```
index.php
| app
    | thisfolder
        | ex1
            | controllers
                controller.php
            | models
            | views
                index.htm
    | templates
        main.htm
```

In my main.htm template, I have a basic page set up that has a navbar and a footer, which should render the content being called between everything using `<include href="{{ @content }}" />`

**Template**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Testing</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
        <!-- CSS/JS FILES -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/uikit.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/custom.css">
        <script src="/assets/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/assets/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="uk-offcanvas-content">
            <!--HEADER-->

            <header style="background-color: #fff; border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2" data-uk-sticky="show-on-up: true; animation: uk-animation-slide-top">
                <div class="uk-container">
                    <nav id="navbar" data-uk-navbar="mode: click;">
                        <div class="uk-navbar-center">
                            <a class="uk-navbar-item uk-logo" href="#">Testing</a>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </header>

            <include href="{{ @content }}" />

            <footer class="uk-section uk-section-small" style="margin-bottom: 60px">
                <div class="uk-container">
                    <p class="uk-text-small uk-text-center">Built with <a href="http://getuikit.com" title="Visit the UIkit 3 site" target="_blank" data-uk-tooltip><span data-uk-icon="uikit"></span></a> & <a href="https://fatfreeframework.com" title="Visit the F3 Site" target="_blank" data-uk-tooltip>F3</a> </p>
                </div>
            </footer>
            <!--/FOOTER-->
            <!-- BOTTOM BAR -->
            <div class="uk-section uk-section-xsmall uk-section-default uk-position-bottom uk-position-fixed" style="border-top: 1px solid #f2f2f2">
                <div class="uk-container uk-container-small uk-text-small">
                    <div class="uk-grid" data-uk-grid>
                        <div class="uk-width-expand">
                            <a href="#" class="uk-link-reset">
                                <span data-uk-icon="icon: arrow-right"></span>
                                <span class="uk-visible@s">Testing | <small>Page Rendered in {{ @loadtime }} seconds.</small></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /BOTTOM BAR -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The trouble is, when I try to load the page with my browser, I get a completely blank page. The template does not load and neither does the content.

If, however, I change the name of the content to anything other than "index", the template loads fine but the content renders in an error:

> Unable to open ex1/views/indexd.htm

So from what I can tell, the path is correct, *it only "works" if I am pointing `$content` to a file that does not exist in my views folder*.

Why will my pages not render properly, and how can I fix it?

Comment: we need the template script. That seems to be where its pulling your template

Comment: @Hudson You mean `\Template`? That's part of [Fat-Free-Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/views-and-templates#AQuickLookattheF3TemplateLanguage) - Or do you mean the actual code of my template?

Comment: Your template , I meant script not class, I've been coding all day haha, my bad

Comment: @Hudson I've already given the line of my template that is actually pulling the content data, so I'm not sure how showing you my whole template will help, but regardless I will update my question

Comment: Have you got `ini_set("display_errors" , 1)` and `error_reporting(E_ALL)`

Comment: @Hudson Just added that to the top of my index.php file, still blank page though

Comment: Depending on the PHP settings of the server you're on, the errors might be supressed beyond your control. Has this ever worked in the past (but perhaps something with the template changed)? Or is this new code?

Comment: have you `var_dump` `\Template::instance()->render("../templates/$template.htm");`

Comment: this will tell you if the system is working properly, also, systems like this rely on `ob_start()` and `ob_clean()` , have you got these functions enabled?

Comment: @kchason F3 itself has definitely worked before, I'm modifying a project of mine to be a little bit more module. This function itself has worked previously without issue on the same server, same directory even.

Comment: @Hudson I will try the var dump - see my comment to kchason in regards to your other question.

Comment: @Hudson When I change `return` to var_dump, the page renders successfully (Including the template & actual content), but it has `string(2043) "` at the top

Comment: In your `get()` method - should you return the value from `render()`?

Comment: @Hudson And you just helped me figure it out. It's because I wasn't using `echo` on the return from `render()`, which is VERY WEIRD considering it worked fine when not trying to load content?

Comment: @NigelRen No, but I _should_ be `echo`ing it - which I've just realized I wasn't doing thanks to Hudson - but it's still very weird to me that it worked when not loading content.

Comment: OK - don't know the framework but it just seemed to leave the result hanging.  The reason why it might be displaying if the page doesn't exist is that is may be the error handle doing the display.

Comment: @NigelRen That makes sense, and I'm not sure how I missed such a crucial word; "echo". Thank you!